# scale up pic in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap gallery, the images are in thumbnails and on clicking them they show in a hidden div...nice.

Now no matter how big the images are they always fit intot he same size div but...

i now have some small images but they are not scaling up - they appear in 'popup' div smaller than the div itself. I use img-reponsive with no luck.

Anyone know how bootstrap deals with small images scaling up?

My modal popup div

```
   <!-- modal popup dialog-->
   <div class="modal fade" id="image-gallery" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    </button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title" id="image-gallery-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <img id="image-gallery-image" class="img-responsive" src="" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="show-previous-image">Previous</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-8 text-justify" id="image-gallery-caption">This text will be overwritten by jQuery</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <button type="button" id="show-next-image" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my bootstrap html

```
                <div class="col-xs-6  col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-title="" data-caption="" data-image="/img/cakes/photo_sq48.jpg" data-target="#image-gallery">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/cakes/photo_sq48.jpg" alt="photo_sq48 missing" />
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Comment: Why not use css property `transform: scale(X)` (where X is the scale factor)? CSS can automatically scale down to fit the div, but you need to tell it to scale up using codes.

Comment: thx for response. Can you elaborate on this in an answer? If i wanted it 100% of modal dialog what would that css look like?

Comment: Can you please create a lil functional example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Would be easier for everybody to help then :)